# Short way to check a variable is not equal to two numbers

Tags: c#

I have to check writerId is not equal to 0 or 1. here is what I wrote.

```
int writerId = foo();
if(writerId != 0 && writerId != 1)
{
 // do something
}
```

Is there any short way to write the same if statement?

Comment: if writerId is unsigned int, just writerId > 1

Comment: This depends on the type of `writerId`.

Comment: `writerId` is int. eddied the question.

Comment: If writerId is positive..
if(writerId > 1) {..}

Comment: `int` is a signed type, so `if (writerId > 1)` does not have the same meaning as the example code.

Comment: why do you need to shorten this?

Comment: Oh, I can see why you might want to shorten the above.  The pythonic if writerId in [0,1]:  is nice.

Answer (score 6):

This is shorter, but considerably harder to understand:

```
if ((writerId & ~1) != 0)
```

The `writerId & ~1` operation unsets the least significant bit in the number -- the only two numbers that would be equal to 0 after this operation are 1 and 0, so if the result is not 0 then it must not have been 0 or 1.

However, you are severely sacrificing readability.  Sometimes the shortest code is not the most readable.  I would stick with what you have.

Answer (score 2):

If readability is a concern when viewing this piece of code.. you could always move it into its own boolean method so that it reads nicer in the context of the other code:

```
bool IsValid(int writerId) {
    return writerId != 0 && writerId != 1;
}
```

Then your code can at least read a little bit nicer:

```
if (IsValid(writerId)) {
    // do something
}
```

..I will leave the appropriate naming for the method up to you. I generally do this if there is no easier way to make the code read nicer without it becoming more complex.

Comment: The above doesn't seem so hot, splitting up trivial bits of code into separate functions doesn't help legibility!

Comment: @RobertMoskal It can be, it really depends on the circumstance.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I disagree. Perhaps this is a bit of a trivial example, coupled with the fact that I didn't really name the function appropriately (`WriterIdIsValid` seemed a bit weird..). It is very situational though.. so I thought it worth a mention.

Comment: +1 for Simon. If extracting bits of code improves in making the intention of the code more explicit, then do it! In this case 0 and 1 are just magic numbers. Zero I'd understand, because it's the default, but 1? Extracting it into an `IsValid` method at least explains to me that 1 isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (foo() >> 1 != 0)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to be a reoccuring thing in my daily work. I wrote an extension for it at some point:

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static bool EqualsAny<T>(this T value, params T[] comparables)
    {
        return comparables.Any(element => object.Equals(value, element));
    }

    public static bool EqualsNone<T>(this T value, params  T[] comparables)
    {
        return !EqualsAny(value, comparables);
    }
}
```

So instead of `(writerId != 0 && writerId != 1)` you can write `(!writerId.EqualsAny(0, 1))` or `(writerId.EqualsNone(0, 1))`. In this case, I probably wouldn't use the EqualsNone method, because it actually lowers readability. I might not use the method for this case at all anyway. It mostly helps with readability with long enum names that would cause long or wrapped lines. And as always it's a matter of opinion at any rate. ;)